# Casting an object with a conversion operator fails

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

So I have this Object, say DoubleContainer.

```
public struct DoubleContainer
{
    private readonly double _value;

    private DoubleContainer(double value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(DoubleContainer doubleContainer)
    {
        return doubleContainer._value;
    }

    public static DoubleContainer Create(double value)
    {
        return new DoubleContainer(value);
    }
}
```

Casting it works as expected in almost all cases, except where it's passed into a function as an Object.

The following code generates an InvalidCastException if I pass in a DoubleContainer:

```
public double GetDouble(Object input)
{
    return (double)input;
}
```

I can get it to work if I do use dynamic:

```
public double GetDouble(Object input)
{
   return (double)(dynamic)input;
}
```

My problem with this solution is that Visual Studio grays out the (dynamic), because it should be redundant, so someone may remove it. Also I don't know if there are any other places in the codebase where this same problem may occur.

Is there anything I can do to my implementation of DoubleContainer what will make my first implementation of GetDouble() work? I tried adding another implicit conversion operator from Object to DoubleContainer, but "user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed"....

Comment: Why would you wrap a `double` into a class just to cast it to `object`?  If this is just an example and you have a more complex class with a valid cast to `double` then why cast it to `object`.  Basically you should really look at your design if you have these type of casting issues.

Comment: I agree that our code design in this area is questionable. Unfortunately redesigning at this point in the release is out of the question. I'm just trying to find a fix for a bug that hopefully somewhat robust and not super hacky.

Comment: @Ash That class itself is super hacky

Comment: You could do something like `var dc = input as DoubleContainer; if(dc != null) return (double)dc; else return (double)input;`  I guess it really depends on what all you expect to pass into `GetDouble`.

Comment: "Is there anything I can do to my implementation of DoubleContainer what will make my first implementation of GetDouble() work" - nope, there is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make it work, because you can only unbox boxed struct (this is what you are doing with `(double) input`) to the exact undelying type, for the reasons best described in this [article](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) by Eric Lippert. So whenever you do `(double) someObject` - it will only work if object is actually a `double`, not `int`, not `float` , not `DoubleContainer`. If you expect other types - you can better use `Convert.ToDouble`. For that to work with your type you need it to implement `IConvertible`:

```
public struct DoubleContainer : IConvertible
{
    private readonly double _value;

    private DoubleContainer(double value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(DoubleContainer doubleContainer)
    {
        return doubleContainer._value;
    }

    public static DoubleContainer Create(double value)
    {
        return new DoubleContainer(value);
    }

    public double ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider) {
        return _value;
    }

    public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider) {
        // delegate to your double
        return ((IConvertible) _value).ToBoolean(provider);
    }

    // ... rest is skipped ...
```

Then it will work with

```
public double GetDouble(Object input)
{
    return Convert.ToDouble(input);
}
```

Comment: That article you linked explained it very well.

Comment: @Ash: Glad to hear it!  This is a very frequently asked question about casts.

Answer (score 1):

When casting an object to double, compiler does not know that it should call your existing `operator double`, so it will not insert any call to your user defined operator double.

When you insert `dynamic` in the middle, compiler will generate something like "if this reference has an operator double, call it`, so it works.

So, it actually cannot work as long as you cast a `System.Object` to a double, while code suggested by @juharr, slightly modified, will work:

```
public double GetDouble(Object input)
{
    if (input is DoubleContainer)
    {
        var dc = (DoubleContainer)input; 
        return (double)dc;
    }
    return (double)input;
}
```

EDIT: modified code as per @SergiyKlimkov comment

Comment: DoubleContainer is a struct. So "input as DoubleContainer" will not compile. It needs to replace by "(DoubleContainer)input ".